# First Item in list getting wrong Image

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have been struggling with this issue the past few days. I have tried everything available on stack overflow but I couldn't fix this issue.

This bug is appearing only when my first item doesn't have a valid url and it is happening only for the first element.
After I scroll down the correct image is loaded.

The basic idea is that I put a temporary image that will be replaced with the image loaded from a JSON. If no url(or invalid) a specific default should be displayed depending on the type of the animal I am displaying(if it is a dog will display a dog image, if it is a cat will display a cat image and so on).

Here is the code in the ImageLoader class I use:

```
    package ro.nextlogic.petsplus.utils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import ro.nextlogic.petsplus.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageLoader {

    static MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    static FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;    
    /**
     * The maximum number of threads used when loading images. 
     */
    private static final int MAX_THREADS = 5;
    private Context context;

    private volatile static ImageLoader instance;

    /** Returns singleton class instance */
    public static ImageLoader getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (ImageLoader.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new ImageLoader(context);
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private ImageLoader(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);

        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREADS);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.default_other;
    public void displayImage(String url, ImageView imageView, final int REQUIRED_SIZE) {
        if (url == null) {
            return;
        }
        Log.i("BITMAP", "imageView = " + imageView + "\nurl = " + url);
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap!=null && !bitmap.isRecycled() ) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView, REQUIRED_SIZE);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView, final int REQUIRED_SIZE) {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView, REQUIRED_SIZE);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    public static Bitmap getBitmap(final String url, final int REQUIRED_SIZE) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f, REQUIRED_SIZE);
        if(b != null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f, REQUIRED_SIZE);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
               memoryCache.clear();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private static Bitmap decodeFile(final File f, final int REQUIRED_SIZE) {
        try {
            //  Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,o);
            stream1.close();

            //  The new size we want to scale to
//            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;   // 70 is best for Thumbnail
            //  Get the width and height of the image
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            //  Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }
            //  Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
//          Log.e("IMAGELOADER", "FileNotFoundException: ", e1);
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            Log.e("IMAGELOADER", "IOException: ", e2);
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public final String url;
        public final ImageView imageView;
        public final int REQUIRED_SIZE;
        public PhotoToLoad(final String u, final ImageView i, final int rq){
            url=u;
            imageView=i;
            REQUIRED_SIZE = rq;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url, photoToLoad.REQUIRED_SIZE);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                a.runOnUiThread(bd);
            }catch(Throwable th){
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }
        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap != null)
                Utils.imageViewAnimatedChange(context, photoToLoad.imageView, bitmap);
//                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }
}
```

and this is how I call it:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.shelter_animal_rowlayout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.animalImg = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.shelter_animal_image);
        holder.animalName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.shelter_animal_name);
        holder.animalDescription = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.shelter_animal_description);
        rowView.setTag(holder);            
    } else {
        holder = ((ViewHolder) rowView.getTag());
    }

    AnimalItem animalItem = filteredModelItemsArray.get(position);
    if (animalItem != null) {
        // Display the animal name, set "Unknown" if not available
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(animalItem.name) &&                  // Not empty
                !animalItem.name.contains("Unknown")) {     // Not Unknown
            holder.animalName.setText(animalItem.name);
        } else {
            holder.animalName.setText(R.string.shelter_animal_name);
        }

        // Display the animal description, set "Unknown" if not available
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(animalItem.description) &&                   // Not empty
                !animalItem.description.contains("Unknown")) {  // Not Unknown
            holder.animalDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml(animalItem.description));    
        } else {
            holder.animalDescription.setText(R.string.shelter_animal_description);
        }

        // Display the animal image
        if (animalItem.photo != null) {
            imageLoader.displayImage(animalItem.photo, holder.animalImg, 70);
        } else if (animalItem.animal.contains("Dog")) {
            holder.animalImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_dog);
        } else if (animalItem.animal.contains("Cat")) {
            holder.animalImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_cat);
        } else {
            holder.animalImg.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_help);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "NO animals retrieved from server!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

return rowView;
```

}

`animalItem.photo` is the url from JSON
`animalItem.animal` is the type of the animal also got from JSON

I should mention that the text is displayed ok ... only the image is wrong and only for the first element(when the photo is not available).

If anyone could point me in the right direction or tell what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I think I fixed the issue by not using WeakHashMap anymore and saving in the Map the hashCode for each ImageView. So this is what I changed:

```
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
```

into

```
private Map<Integer, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer, String>());
```

and for saving and getting the values:

```
imageViews.put(imageView, url);
```

into

```
imageViews.put(imageView.hashCode(), url);
```

and

```
imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
```

into

```
imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView.hashCode());
```

**SOLUTION:**
I have fixed the issue without affecting the performance by adding a method that cancels the loading of the image:

This is the method(declared in ImageLoader):

```
public void cancelDisplayTaskFor(ImageView imageView) {
    imageViews.remove(imageView);
}
```

And will call this method in the custom ArrayAdapter where I set the image:

```
            // Display the animal image
        if (animalItem.photo != null) {
            imageLoader.displayImage(animalItem.photo, holder.animalImg, 70);
        } else if (animalItem.animal.contains("Dog")) {
            imageLoader.cancelDisplayTaskFor(holder.animalImg);
            holder.animalImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_dog);
        } else if (animalItem.animal.contains("Cat")) {
            imageLoader.cancelDisplayTaskFor(holder.animalImg);
            holder.animalImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_cat);
        } else {
            imageLoader.cancelDisplayTaskFor(holder.animalImg);
            holder.animalImg.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_help);
        }
```

Hope this will help someone else :)

Comment: Your code is too unreadable in its current form. But I can tell you its a thread issue which also is related to the way convertviews are loaded. If you debug at first run with breakpoints without threads it will become more clear.

Comment: What do you mean unreadable ? What you can't understand ? Maybe I can modify it(remove some methods not related to the issue) ? Also I don't think it is because of the threads, everything is working ok except the first element and only when it doesn't have an image to be loaded. My guess is that is regarding the reuse of Views inside the ListView ... I tested with View at position 0 being redrawn every time and it seems to be working that way(but it affects the performance of the ListView and I don't want that).

Comment: Hi Lonut did you get solution for this issue i am also getting same issue, if you got the solution then please help me to sort out the same, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
   // change this code inside your imageloader


      public void run() {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if(bitmap != null)
         {
              Utils.imageViewAnimatedChange(context, photoToLoad.imageView, bitmap);

         }
        else
         {
              imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);// so if bitmap is null it will set  this default image
         }
    }
```

Comment: This didn't fix the issue. And I don't seem to find the reason for doing this ... The default image(if url not valid) is set before(I don't have a problem with the temporary image that is shown until the image is loaded - those work ok). But still thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

but you have to replace the adapter list or array before notifying (forgot to mention), then notifyDataChanged()

Comment: This didn't fix the issue. Bu still thank you for the answer.

Comment: I can't think of how I could achieve this for my application. I would have to re-think how I get the data and how I set it in the adapter, and this seems a lot of work for a small issue like this(as I mentioned this is happening only for the first Item, I don't even have the bug where wrong images are shown when fast scrolling)

Comment: My guess is that this is happening because I use the ListView holder(to reuse the rows). I left the first item to be inflated each time and the bug disappeared, but I don't want this because it affects the performance of the ListView.

Comment: I have managed to call notifyDataSetChanged() inside the custom ArrayAdapter like this: `//Display the animal image
   if (animalItem.photo != null) {
    imageLoader.displayImage(animalItem.photo, holder.animalImg, 70);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
   } else if (animalItem.animal.contains("Dog")) {
             holder.animalImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_dog);
   } else if (animalItem.animal.contains("Cat")) {
    holder.animalImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_cat);
   } else {
    holder.animalImg.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_help);
   }`

Comment: But using this method the performance is even worse than not reusing the first element in the ListView and inflating it each time.

Comment: if u set the notifydatachanged inside the adapter, you are calling it so many times, and you cant control that. think about an update method, maybe an asynctask to retrieve your database and call the update or notifydatachanged in the post part of the asynctask.